# EF 4.0 with oracle provider running very slow

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I hope you can help me with that.

I have a very simple query running on oracle with the ODT managed provider:

```
return  Ent.TABLE.ToList();
```

witch gives me **34k records**, but it's taking as long as **45 seconds** to give me the result, but if I run the query (Select * from TABLE) from Sql Developer or TOAD, the query runs very fast,in less than 1 second.

My current model has more or less 35 tables.

it's happening in several tables not only in the one I mentioned.

is there anything I can do to improve performance?

Comment: In SQL Developer or TOAD, are you measuring the time required to fetch the first row?  Or the time to fetch the 34,000th row?

Comment: well, the time to fetch 250 rows, but even if I limit my query to 250 records on EF it's still taking a lot of time.